# How can I intelligently update a Mongoose document based on variable request data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

For my Edit user route, I will need to handle a number of different possible circumstances. A user could update their profile and only change their email address or password, but they might update a whole range of other profile information at once too.

The advantage of `findOneAndUpdate` is that you can pass the update object and it will only change those fields from the request that are different than the saved data. This is great! One HUGE problem -- this query bypasses validators and middleware for some reason (even with `runValidators=true`, it bypasses pre-save hooks, meaning password updates bypass being encrypted).

So the solution I keep seeing everywhere is to do a `findOne` or `findById`, update fields manually, and then run `user.save()`.

However, with a fairly complicated user record, that means my route would look something like this and would be very hard to maintain:

```
exports.editUser = async function(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    let user = await db.User.findById(id);
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.fullName = req.body.fullName;
    user.password = req.body.password;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    user.otherField = req.body.otherField;
    let updatedUser = await user.save();
    return res.status('200').json(user); 
  }
```

Is there any way to mimic the behavior of passing the updates object to Mongoose where I can just give it `req.body` and let it only update the fields that are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge

_.merge(user, req.body)

This will merge **EVERYTHING **.  Use only if you don't care about security.

To limit to certain fields without going crazy:

```
const { f1, f2, f3 } = req.body;
_.merge(user, { f1, f2, f3})
```

Or refer to this: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#pick
Slightly non-obvious feature in lodash.

```
_.merge(user, _.pick(req.body, ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']))
```

Comment: What would be the security concerns of this?

Comment: Also, based on the fact that an external library with security concerns is needed to make this work, should I assume this method of handling updates is not standard? Is it more common to set up update/edit routes like in my (lengthy) example above?

Comment: lodash is just a functional programming library. The features in there are common in other functional programming languages.

Merging in this case simply what you did, but for every field that is supplied.

I.e. if someone put a { isAdmin: true, password: "" }, it would also be merged in. Probably not what you intend.

Comment: Well the main issue is you have zero validation so far. Obviously you want to ensure that the correct user is logged in, and that he is allowed to change only his own account. And the user can only modify things he is allowed to modify.

So reasonably, _.merge(user, _.pick(req.body, ['email', 'profile_pic', 'status', ...])). You need to name whatever the user is allowed to include. And check that he's allowed to include it. And whether what is included is not too ridiculous (e.g. a 10000 character display name is not ok). Mongoose can deal with some of that in the model.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I'll already be protecting this route behind authorization middleware, and I have some sensible validators and hooks in the model. It makes sense to combine with _pick as you said, since there will reasonably only be a finite number of things the user could modify.

Comment: @ipenguin67 Oh yes, there's 1 caveat here. This assumes that your previous solution works. I.e. each item is typed in the schema (and not mixed https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#mixed). In that case, you need to use markModified.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -- currently not using any mixed and have no plans to :)